# How to obtain pointer from reflect.Value in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, interface

As far as I know methods with pointer receivers only implement interfaces for pointers. I want to utilize the `encoding.TextMarshaler` interface which must be implmented with a pointer. How can I therefore obtain a pointer using reflection.

The following does not work because as mentionend a value does not implement the interface:

```
v.Interface().(encoding.TextUnmarshaler)
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Addr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use v.[Addr()](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Addr).Interface().(encoding.TextUnmarshaler) to get the address. This assumes that v references an [addressable](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.CanAddr) value.